# Shimano Deore XT: is 9-speed no longer continued? (Europe)

Tags: shimano, speed, europe

For an upgrade I'm trying to decide whether to change to 9-speed or 10-speed cassette, chain, derailleur, shifter and crank.

On the european Shimano website there are not many words about 9-speed components in the Deore XT Group and a european reseller has marked many items as "discontinued".

When choosing 9-speed today will I probably have trouble finding new components in about five years? Has Shimano officially discontinued 9-speed?

Comment: 9 speed is Alivio and Acera these days. I'd expect you'd be fine for at least 5 years if you're ok with these part levels.

Comment: If you are going to upgrade to XT, why not to go with the latest 8000 11-speed one?

Comment: @Klaster_1 Hub compatibility?

Comment: @Frisbee Shimano 11-speed MTB cassetes use the old driver body, no need to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shimano has a pretty good track record of wear parts availability for older groupsets. I am using 8-speed myself, and there are several European mail order stores as well as local shops that have spare cassettes and chains.  I would expect that 9-speed spare parts aren't going away either.

The problem with off-road groups is that rear derailleurs are not compatible between 9- and 10-speed, so you need to change shifters, derailleurs, cassette and chain if you need to switch later.

EDIT: To clarify, even though 9-speed XT groups have not been sold in a while, XT-level 9-speed wear parts are still available. For 8-speed it looks like spares above Deore/Tiagra level are no longer available.

Comment: Good answer, but with the caveat that Shimano has NOT discontinued 9-speed components, and should continue to offer them, but at lower-tier group levels.

Comment: Cassettes and chains are still available.

Comment: There are also other Shimano-compatible brands with 9-speed offerings.

Answer (score 0):

If the freehub will take 9 or 10 then why would you not go 10?

Why would you *upgrade* to 9 when you can as easily upgrade to 10?

[Cassette Spacers 2013](http://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/Cassette_Spacers_2013_3978.html)

Comment: Because going for 9-spd is cheaper

Comment: @EricSmekens Not upgrading is even cheaper

Comment: 9-speed has larger tolerances and may or may not work better when dirty and knocked slightly out of adjustment.

Comment: @ojs If tolerance of wide gaps was a driving factor then why upgrade at all?    May or may not?  1x11 has a big place in CX where you get a lot of mud and knocked around so this is that argument is not holding dirt with me.  Do you see any high end dirt racers run a lower gear count?  Do you have any empirical evidence to support that may?

Comment: There are a lot of high-end Downhill/Freeride bikes that ship with 9-speed. Just checking, and the latest/expensive model of Commencal comes with 7-speed. Sometimes there is just no need for those extra speeds. And maybe in this case, 9 in enough, and go for 9.

Comment: @EricSmekens  If 9 is enough then why is there an 11 at all.  The question is downhill / freeride?   So the OP feels the need to upgrade to more speeds but anything past 9 is too much?

Comment: I believe Yngwie Malmsteen has the answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHZ48AE3TOI&t=10s